# Update tables via c#, wpf and entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-entities

I have some tables in database. Each table is connected by foreign key-primary key construct. The scenario is i have to delete data from that tables on single button.

So how do i retrieve and delete particular data on single button?

[image: This is the list view of main table.]

I would like to display respective names rather than IDs shown in the view.

[image: Item table]

Item table has item id and name. While in above shown grid, it shows itemid, i would like to have item name instead.

[image: Transporter Table]

Same as above case, in above view we have transporter id. I would like to display transporter name.

So there will not be any id, it will be names in grid view. The respective ID columns are foreign key to their counter table. How do i display name column from respective table and also able to update/delete it?

Comment: which one scenario are you using: connected or disconnected?

Comment: disconnected, database first.

Comment: if you are using disconnected scenario, you should track changes manually, take a look here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/update-entity-graph-using-dbcontext.aspx. You'll have to traverse the entire graph manually to mark modified objects.

Comment: @nikis i have updated question with more details.